# How to properly inject IOptions into DB context class if DB Context is located in another project?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have multiple projects in the solution, and use two DB contexts,
therefore I had to specify which context when creating migrations with the *-c MyDbContext* argument.
However, this doesn't work if I only specify the DB context in the Web project's startup.

MyApp.Web - WebAPI project, in where I register DB context in startup via *AddDbContext* method.
MyApp.Persistence - project where migrations and db context is located.

So when I try to add a migration like:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration -c MyAppDbContext --project MyApp.Persistence
```

it fails.

However, when *OnConfiguring* method is overriden it works, when everything is done again:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        //  optionsBuilder.UseOracle(...);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I supply `IOptions<DBConfig>` assuming `DBConfig` class contains info about connection string, schema, and the migrations table, if I only register the options in the *MyApp.Web's* `Startup.cs`?
My guess is that EF core ignores startup project's `startup.cs` and builds the DBContext's project?

Basically I'd like to achieve this dependency injection in my db context:

```
public MyAppDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IOptions<DBConfig> databaseSettings)
    : base(options)
{
    _databaseSettings = databaseSettings.Value;
}
```

However, don't know how and where to register `DBConfig` as options configuration.

Comment: There's no need for that. The database setting options are passed through `DbContextOptions` already. Migrations *depend* on this, because that's how they pass command-line arguments to the contexts. What does `DbConfig` contain that can't be specified in `AddDbContext` or `DbContextOptions<>` ?

Comment: `However, this doesn't work if I only specify the DB context in the Web project's startup.` it does - you need one `AddDbContext` for each DbContext which means you can specify different settings for each easily. Post your actual code and explain what you want to do

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is correct, however, I couldn't also create migrations if my DB context didn't have a parameterless constructor, so I had to add one.

Comment: That would happen if you tried to create migrations using a separate project that doesn't contain the startup code. In that case the tool doesn't know how to create the contexts. There are several solutions for this. 1) you can tell the tool where the startup is with the `--startup-project` parameter. 2) you can create a [design time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) that produces the DbContexts. This will allow you to work with migrations without the startup project